# Is every hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the boundary of an open domain?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

We know if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded  $C^k$ domain, then its boundary $\partial\Omega$ is a $C^k$ compact hypersurface of dimension $n-1$.

Is it true that every $m-$dimensional compact hypersurface is the boundary of a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$??

Presumably the $C^k$ smoothness of the hypersurface implies $C^k$ smoothness of the domain.

---

Definition of hypersurface:
A set $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a $C^k$-hypersurface if for each $x \in \Gamma$, there is an open set $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ containing $x$ and a $C^k$ function $\phi$ such that $$U \cap \Gamma = \{ y \in U \mid \phi(y) = 0\}$$ and $\nabla \phi(y) \neq 0$ for all $y \in U \cap \Gamma$.

Definition of $C^k$-domain:
[image]

Comment: I am having some trouble with the first paragraph. Do we really know this? Assuming what definition of hypersurface and dimension?

Comment: You might as well thow in a definition of "domain", too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm A domain is usually taken to be an open connected set, no?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I think it is true if we say $C^k$ domain. Let me try to find a reference.

Comment: But what is a $C^k$ domain?

Comment: @MikeMiller I added a definition.

Comment: A smooth Jordan curve in the plane, parametrized with respect to arc length, is a compact hypersurface in ${\mathbb R}^2$. That it is bounding an open domain is not easy to prove even in the smooth setting.

Comment: I think this can probably be proved for arbitrary compact hypersurfaces with some homological duality theorem.

Comment: With smoothness, it's far easier. Look at the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem, e.g., in Guillemin and Pollack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof when the compact hypersurface is connected.

A compact hypersurface $H$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is orientable, hence if it is connected then $$H_{n-1}(H)\cong \mathbb Z$$
By Alexander duality, the zeroeth reduced cohomology group of the complement of $H$ in $S^n$ is free abelian of rank $1$, hence the hypersurface divides $S^n$ (considered as $\mathbb R^n$ with an additional point) into two components. $H$ is equal to the boundary of each of these components, which are both open sets. When we pass back to $\mathbb R^n$ via stereographic projection, one of these components will be bounded and the other unbounded. The hypersurface bounds the bounded component, so we are done.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote; but perhaps it was felt the smoothness issue wasn't (adequately) addressed?

Comment: @user86418 It's pretty clear that a domain with a $C^k$ boundary is a $C^k$ domain from the definition.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. It is hard to understand due to unfamiliar content but I just wanted confirmation anyway.

Comment: @Abbre you're welcome. You can come back and look at it after you've learned some more algebraic topology. I'm pretty sure there's no easy way to prove it without some amount of algebraic topology, it's a notoriously difficult problem that world famous mathematicians in the 19th century published incorrect proofs for for $n=2$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes I think you're right, there is no easy proof.

Comment: @MattSamuel: It was rash (of me) to attempt to guess the mind of a down-voter. :)

Comment: @user86418 Here is a more reasonable guess: I forgot to specify that for this proof to work the hypersurface has to be connected.

Comment: Every manifold wich is boundary of an open set is orientable, as i was reading here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377236/inducing-orientations-on-boundary-manifolds, so do you think should we also ask for the manifold to be oriented?

Comment: @Alicia Sad thing is that this stuff is growing foggy in my memory. I was a year out of grad school when I wrote this and my focus was not topology. I understand it at least (it hasn't been that long!) but I wouldn't have written this now. You're free to edit my ancient answer.