# orientation problem in computing a 2-form integral

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $  \{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 = 1, 0\le z \le 1\}$ and $α = z^2 xdy$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Let $ω = dα$. Compute $\int_{\mathcal{C}} ω$.

If we use Stokes formulae: $\int_{\mathcal{C}} ω = \int_{\partial \mathcal{C}} \alpha  = \int_{\mathbb{S}^1 \times \{0\}} z^2x dy - \int_{\mathbb{S}^1 \times \{1\}} z^2 x dy$.

1- Why does the orientation (the minus before the second integral) change between the two circles at $z=0$ and $z=1$?

2- If we use Stokes formulate differently with $V$ the volume of $\mathcal{C}$:

$\int_{\mathcal{C}=\partial V} \omega = \int_{V} dω == \int_{V} d\circ dω =0 $.

There is an orientation problem in the 1- and a false reasonning in the 2- I can't see.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of orientation, you have to choose a normal vector which points outward.

[Inducing orientations on boundary manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377236/inducing-orientations-on-boundary-manifolds)

Comment: Thank you for the link. In that case, If we choose counter clockwise to be the direct direction and switch to cylindrical coordinates,  I feel like the minus sign should rather go with the first integral: as $\theta$ increases counter clockwise, the normal vector points inward for $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \{0\}$  and outwards for $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \{1\}$?

Comment: The best way tounderstand this is to consider a continuous $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\int_a^bf(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F'=f$, the orientation of $\mathbb{R}$ points towards $+\infty$, the induced orientation on $a$ in the interval $[a,b]$ points towards $-\infty$ because it points outwards. This is exactly the same if you consider a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ even something more complicated by using Fubini.

Comment: Concerning Stokes, the cylinder is not a boundary.