# Induced orientations on manifolds - explanation and example

Tags: calculus, manifolds, examples-counterexamples, orientation

I learned about orientations on manifolds and induced orientation on the surface and I don't get the idea. When I search online I find explanations with different definitions.

Here is how we defined orientaion:
[image: orientation definition]

The induced orientation was defined using compostion of the orientation with the containment function multiplied with $(-1)^m$ where m is the dimension of the manifold.

What is the $(-1)^m$ for? I would be glad to get an **intuitive explanation** and an **example** of induced orientation on a simple manifold (preferably one from odd dimension).

Comment: The funny sign ensures that Stokes theorem becomes $\int_Md\omega=\int_{\partial M}\omega$.

Comment: You don't say so, but, I presume that $M$ is a manifold with boundary? And that the "induced orientation" is an orientation defined on its boundary $\partial M$?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes and yes :)

Comment: What does " compostion of the orientation with the containment function " mean?

Comment: @Arctic Char $Ox0 = (-1)^m * (Ox composition i)$ where $i: R^(m-1) -> H^m i(u1, ..., um-1) = (u1, ..., um-1,0)$

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/380635/629362) explain briefly the term $(-1)^m$. A more detailed explanation requires some understanding of differential forms and ultimately the Stokes theorem. If you are not there yet, I suggest you come back to this later.